# What's the fast way to get the file name?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

```
myVar = "D:\\mainfolder\\subf1\\subf2\\subf3\\file.txt";
```

How can I get `file.txt` conveniently in .NET 2.0 with C#?
What I know is split with `\\` and try to get the last member.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
string fileNameOnly = Path.GetFileName("D:\\mainfolder\\subf1\\subf2\\subf3\\file.txt");
```

should return `file.txt`

Linking [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx)'s class documentation on MSDN. Has many other convenient methods.

Comment: Hell, yes :) Seriously, I'm not sure if it is t.h.e. f.a.s.t.e.s.t w/o looking at the implementation but I can assure you it is the easiest and less risky to do. But why are you concerned about speed? Are you parsing millions of paths per second?

Comment: @jcolebrand: Fastest is what is *fastest*.

Comment: Tautological definitions are tautological

Comment: @Nawaz don't be so picky about a little simple thing like this. The reality is that Path.GetFileName parses the text, it takes into account environment path separators for you automatically. For example, the same code in Linux will work even though the path separator in Linux is `/`. So Path.GetFileName is also `portable`. Yes, surely one can implement something that executes `faster`, but not without overlooking many details that can make your code fail miserably. The Path class is used by E.V.E.R.Y. B.O.D.Y. so I would use the damn thing.

Comment: @Icarus: I understand your point; even if it's not fastest, or even a little bit slow, I wouldn't care for most of my life. Just wanted to know how fast can it get the filename (and the title of the question triggers this thought in my mind), hence my comment. +1.

Comment: @jcolebrand: Never mind. Icarus understands what *fastest* means. You just define "define" , and then I will define "fastest" for you ;-)

Comment: Not so. We have a very good common understanding of fastest. Youre just being difficult.

Answer (score 7):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(myVar);
```

Comment: It is if you want to get the file name in the general case (i.e. without knowing the input in advance, or without there being any constraints on the input).

Comment: @Nawas,Open a question and ask for the f.a.s.t.e s.t (whatever kind of fastest u want). There might be chockingly effective hided methods to split a string....

Comment: @nawaz This answer was the fastest, only 2 minutes after the question.

Comment: @Nawas it is the fastest currently available that doesn't break under certain weird input strings.